# Не работает remote деплой в idea на tomcat 9

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat, развертывание

Как задеплоить проект на удаленный сервер tomcat используя IDEA? Если вручную закидывать то что получается на выходе, то всё работает,а если автоматизировать, то нет. Читал, что нужно добавить опции к JVM, но куда их добавлять? Сервер на CentOS 7

```
CATALINA_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=%my.jmx.port%
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

Ошибка при подключении:

```
Error running 'Remote': Unable to connect to the 'server_ip':1099
```

netstat -lp

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      724/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8009               [::]:*                  LISTEN      8700/java           
tcp6       0      0 [::]:webcache           [::]:*                  LISTEN      8700/java           
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      724/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 localhost:mxi           [::]:*                  LISTEN      8700/java           
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name     Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10496    1/systemd            /run/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     10513    1/systemd            /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7618     1/systemd            /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12746    1/systemd            /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было просто изменить `/etc/hosts`

```
ipv4_сервера hostname
ipv6_сервера hostname (Не обязательно)
```

Так же создать в `tomcat_home/bin/setenv.sh` со следующим содержимым

```
CATALINA_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=%my.jmx.port%
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```